# Why is blockhash not safe for random numbers?

Tags: solidity

I'm thinking of a smart contract for a casino type game that looks like this:

- A "roll" function, which stores some input parameters (eg the user's bet), and the block number
- A "verify" function, which takes the previously stored roll, and uses the hash of the block that came after the roll as a random number, and verifies if the user won their bet

The solidity docs say:

> Do not rely on block.timestamp, now and blockhash as a source of randomness, unless you know what you are doing.
> Both the timestamp and the block hash can be influenced by miners to some degree.

But isn't the whole point of a PoW blockchain that the miners **can't** control the block hash? If they could, wouldn't they be able to do double spend attacks, or simply "steal" all the block rewards for themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Block hash can be accessed by everyone making it vulnerable for random number generation because they become very deterministic. Not only can it be accessed by everyone but in this case can be tampered with by the block producers (The validators) depending on the chain.

The recommended solution is to use oracle providers such as chainlink with their chainlink-vrf which is far much safe and nondeterministic.